# How to set the zero angle of a revolute joint differently from SDF

Tags: gazebo, c++, gz-sim

I would like to set the zero angle of a revolute joint differently from how I define the joint frame in the SDF.

For example, take a pendulum constituted by a base link, a revolute joint and a swinging link attached to it. Is there a way to initialize this model with the joint in an arbitrary position, while having the joint position referred to the stable equilibrium position (taken as $\theta=0$)?